# Porting Linux to ARM

Tags: linux, arm

**BACKGROUND**

Off late, I am finding myself increasingly fascinated for better understanding of Linux. Additionally, I want to play around as well, to understand the nuances of it. 
I am not a great Linux hacker. I know C,C++ etc,I have programmed in assembly for ARM and other processors, I know a bit theoretically of the workings of an OS, to a small extent of how Linux is structured (monolithic kernel etc).

Under this light, I am increasingly interested in how can a particular kernel be ported into an ARM based machine.

**So my questions are:**

1. What are the steps a developer need to take to port a kernel to an ARM based machine.
2. How should the development be, i.e should hardware be made first or development of both hw/sw should run parallely or any other method.
3. If anybody has link of "chronicling" of such an endeavour of designing an ARM based machine  (or any other chip based machine) and then porting a kernel onto it, please do share it.

Comment: Linux has already been ported to ARM machines.

Comment: Yes, I did read it up, but then I am not really sure what does that mean (does it mean, the opcodes are changed for ARM processor ? Then thats the work of the compiler isnt it ? ) Technically what I was thinking of is, perhaps fiddling with the HAL

Comment: Runs below HAL ??? :-o ? I believe you mean the same HAL as Hardware Abstraction Layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're truly interested in finding out what differentiates Linux on one arch from another then you should look at the contents of the `arch/` directory in the kernel source tree.

Comment: damn! yes, I did happen to take a look at it. It will be ages before I get my head around it. Thanks.(Till I get a better answer I am going to tick yours as the one)